# Make nautilus to adjust icons size

Tags: nautilus, icons, thumbnails

In the following picture, I want nautilus to scale up mp3 icon so that it seems as same size as two other thumbnails.

[image]

What I've done but seemed with no luck:

- Manipulating `org.gnome.nautilus.icon-view` settings.
- Trying to making icons larger or smaller with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>

Such bevaiour already has been provided by the Dolphin file manager and in which all icons, either default icons or thumbnails, are approximately in the same size. But unfortunately Nautilus cannot be replaced by Dolphin.

Comment: what is the version of your nautilus?

Comment: @NewUSer I'm using 3.14 on Ubuntu 15.04

Answer (score 0):

The thumbnail indeed is not an icon. Thumbnails are reduced-size versions of pictures, used to help in recognizing and organizing them.

Really, what you are talking about is not a problem  since nautilus deals with each file type as the same.

What I want to say take a look for all directories in your system. All icons have the same size.

Take a look at the icons of the applications, you'll notice that they are affected by size provided by the system and all of them has the same size. for example look at /usr/share/applications.

But Sure a thumbnail maybe with a different size of icons since it's a small sized of a picture that it will take a rate of the original picture and thus varies according to the size of the original one.